# Gnome System Monitor shows wrong data

Tags: ram, memory-usage, system-monitor

Why is gnome system monitor showing wrong data in memory usage? I installed KSysGuard and it shows quite similar data to command `free -m` but gnome system monitor is wrong in about 200MB-300MB of RAM.

**I know that there is buffer/cache in RAM**, but gnome system monitor doesn't shows that cache, but it is showing higher data, why? Is it a bug?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

[image: system monitor]

Comment: From the looks it is subtracting `available` memory from `total` to get `970`. The remaining data is probably just cache that is 'used', but can be cleared if needed. Sort of relevant http://www.linuxatemyram.com/  http://askubuntu.com/q/223759/178596